# @after @before used only once, several @test

Tags: java, junit, annotations

I have a test that send emails: one sends a simple email, the second sends an email with attachment and the third sends and email with tags html:

```
@RunWith(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.class)
@ContextConfiguration(locations = {
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/applicationContext.xml",
        "file:src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/spring-mail.xml",
        "classpath:test-applicationContext.xml" })
@TransactionConfiguration(transactionManager = "transactionManager", defaultRollback = false)
public class MailMailTest extends AbstractTransactionalJUnit4SpringContextTests {

    @Autowired
    MailMail mailMail;

    @Value("${mail.mail}")
    private String fromEmail;

    @Autowired
    private MessageSource messages;

    private final static Logger logger = Logger.getLogger(MailMailTest.class);

    @Test
    public void testSendHTMLMail() {
        logger.info("Ini testSendHTMLMail");

        mailMail.sendHTMLMail(
                fromEmail,
                "blah@gmail.com",
                "Prueba envio correo con html",
                "Esto es una prueba <br>"
                        + this.messages.getMessage(
                                "email.requestPasswordRecovery.body",null, "Default",null));

        logger.info("End testSendHTMLMail");
    }

    @Before
    public void setUp() {
        logger.info("** SetUp **");
        try {
            String fileName = "c:/archivo_prueba.txt";
            // File f = new File(fileName);
            FileWriter fw;
            // FileWriter fichero = new FileWriter("c:/prueba.txt",true);
            fw = new FileWriter(fileName, true);

            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(fw);
            pw.println("esto es una prueba");
            pw.close();
            fw.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();

        }

    }

    @Test
    public void testSendMail() {
        logger.info("Inicio prueba testSendMail");

        mailMail.sendMail(fromEmail, "blah@gmail.com",
                "Prueba envio correo con attachment", "Esto es una prueba",
                "c:/archivo_prueba.txt");

        logger.info("Fin prueba testSendMail");
    }

    @After
    public void tearDown() {
        logger.info("** tearDown **");
        File f = new File("c:/archivo_prueba.txt");
        if (f.delete())
            logger.info("El fichero ha sido borrado satisfactoriamente");
        else
            logger.error("El fichero no puede ser borrado");
    }

    @Test
    public void testSendSimpleMail() {
        logger.info("Inicio prueba testSendSimpleMail");

        mailMail.sendSimpleMail(fromEmail, "balh@gmail.com",
                "Prueba envio correo simple", "Esto es una prueba");

        logger.info("Fin prueba testSendSimpleMail");
    }
}
```

In the case of sending an email with attachment I need to create a file, that's why I need: @before for creating a file and @after to delete it. When I run my test @after and @before are called 3 times. Is it possible to call @before and @after just for the method testSendMail()?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use @BeforeClass and @AfterClass to only run the setup and teardown methods a single time (before ALL the tests are run, and after ALL the tests are run).

As far as selectively running the @Before and @After methods based on specific individual unit tests, I don't think that's possible.

Answer (score 2):

It would be better to use JUnit `Rule`s for this task, in particular, the [`TemporaryFolder`](http://junit.org/javadoc/4.10/org/junit/rules/TemporaryFolder.html) rule:

```
@Rule
public TemporaryFolder temp = new TemporaryFolder();

@Test
public void testSendMail() {
    File attachment = temp.newFile("archivo_prueba.txt");

    ... // Write test data to the file

    mailMail.sendMail(fromEmail, "blah@gmail.com",
            "Prueba envio correo con attachment", "Esto es una prueba",
            attachment.getAbsolutePath());
}
```